# Accessing/get the specific content of the Clang AST

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree

below is a picture of the clangAST of a code segment. Does anyone know how to access the attributes in yellow? What are the attributes of the corresponding class?
[image: ClangAST]

Comment: Why don't you inspect the code that prints this, to see how it is collected for printing?

Comment: Thanks for the idea! The way I produced this AST is by simply running `clang++ -Xclang -fsyntax-only -ast-dump src.cpp` Therefore, it's the standard output of the clang++ compiler. So there's not much information to debug.

Comment: You want to access internal data known to Clang. You aren't going to do that without, without working with the Clang source code unless somebody has already done this for you (which I doubt).   So, you need to look inside the Clang source. Once you decide to do that, you can find out where this output is produced, and see how Clang does it.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. It could be the case. Others might have a better idea. Let's wait a bit.

Comment: You can use libclang python bindings. With that you can traverse very easy on the nodes. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang